# iOS - Select/Deselect the marker in Apple maps not working

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am selecting multiple markers on maps. Marker selection is working perfectly and maps delegate method
 `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){}` 
 is being called.

- When callout shown and i am going to deselect the same marker whose callout is showing. Nothing happened.
- When callout shown and i click on any other place and then deselect the previous marker it will deselect the marker.

**Required:**

When callout shown and i am going to deselect the same marker whose callout is showing that need to be deselect.

**Used Stack**

- `xCode` with `swift 4.2`
- `Apple` MapKit
- `MKAnnotationView` as Custom marker

```
class ArtworkView: MKAnnotationView {
var locItem:LocationItem = LocationItem()


override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
  willSet {
    guard let artwork = newValue as? Artwork else {return}
    locItem = artwork.locItem
    if(!artwork.isUser){
        canShowCallout = true
        calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil
        if let imageName = artwork.imageName {
            image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        } else {
            image = nil
        }

        detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailLabel
    }else{
        canShowCallout = false
        calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil
        image = UIImage(named: "gifcurrentloc")
        detailCalloutAccessoryView = nil
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried `mapView(_:didDeselect:)` delegate method?

Comment: @LalKrishna that method is called even if you click on maps other position and it will create problem as i am doing multiselection of marker.

Comment: Can you provide a project sample or more code that can explain the problem?

Comment: why don't you dequeue annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

In `showCallout()/hideCallout()`, use
  `selectAnnotation:/deselectAnnotation:` through the map.

In `showCalloutView:`/`hideCalloutView:`, don't call `setSelected:` on the
  `MKAnnotationView`.

You should not call
  this method directly. An `MKMapView` object calls this method in
  response to user interactions with the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do it, with method `deselectAnnotation` using your `mapView` `outlet`, like:

```
mapView?.deselectAnnotation(annotation: yourAnnotation, animated: false)
```